# print the 1 to 10 numbers using Table

Tags: postgresql

I want to print the 1 to 10 numbers based on table.

Table1

### A

null

### outout is

1
2
3
4
.
.
10

I have a table that table contains only one record...using this table i want to print 1 to 10 numbers please tell me

I written like this...is there any alternate way to write this

select 1 union all  select 2 union all  select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 from table1;

or 
select generate_series(1,10) from table1;

Comment: We help those that help themselves. What have you tried? And what problems are you having? We will help you solve your problems, but we will not write your code for you. Please post code that you have tried as well as a detailed description of the problem you are facing.

Comment: I'm not sure that I even understand what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: How exactly do you want to use data from Table1?

Answer (score 4):

Because your question is almost devoid of useful information, I don't feel bad simply presenting a link to the docs. Take a look at `generate_series()`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

Comment: wow it's great .